# Angular 8 - FormBuilder.group is not preserving arrays

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to set a form group from a `[key:string]:any` but it's not preserving the arrays, when the array has one position it is becoming a number, and when it has more than one I'm getting an error.

```
// Example
let keyList = {
    'TestArray' = [1],
    'Name' = 'John'
};
let formGroup = this.formBuilder.group(keyList);
console.log(formGroup.get('TestArray').value); // 1 instead of [1]
```

Comment: What if you assign `[1,2,3]` to `TestArray`, then what is the output of `console.log(formGroup.get('TestArray').value)`?

Comment: a bunch of errors, the first one is this:

`ERROR TypeError: this.validator is not a function
    at FormControl._runValidator (forms.js:4047)
    at FormControl.updateValueAndValidity (forms.js:4008)
    at new FormControl (forms.js:4614)
    at FormBuilder.control (forms.js:8906)
    at FormBuilder._createControl (forms.js:8966)
    at forms.js:8945
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at FormBuilder._reduceControls (forms.js:8940)
    at FormBuilder.group (forms.js:8859)`

Comment: what is this.myKeyList here? any other formbuilder group? it is unclear, it would be more easy to understand your code if to show proper defination of this.myKeyList.

Comment: Edited, my mistake, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
let keyList = {
        'TestArray' : new FormControl([1]),
        'Name' : 'John'
    };
  let formGroup = this.formBuilder.group(keyList);
  console.log(formGroup.get('TestArray').value);
```

output you will get is some thing like:

```
[1]
0: 1
length: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

To create array of value, you should create formArray

**component.ts**

```
 let keyList = {
    'TestArray':this.formBuilder.array([[1]]),
    'Name' : 'John'
};

let formGroup = this.formBuilder.group(keyList);
console.log(formGroup.get('TestArray').value);
```

Answer (score 0):

`'TestArray' = [1]` implies that you are creating formControl instead of formArray.
For creating formArray use *formBuilder.array*

```
const array = [1,2,3];
let keyList = {
    'TestArray' = this.formBuilder.array(array),
    'Name' = 'John'
};
```

Refer the example for creating different types of controls :-

```
createForm() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      'firstName': 'MyFirstName',
      'lastName' : ['MyLastName'],
      'contact': ['99999999999', [Validators.required]],
      'agree': [true, Validators.requiredTrue],
      'hobbies': this.formBuilder.array(['reading, cooking']),
      'locations': [[], Validators.required],
    });
  }
```